# UITableView shows wrong cell contents

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've stucked with UITableView and adding cells.

I have chat-app based on UITableView for displaying messages. Everything works fine when user opens chat with old messages. But when user adds new message - cell for that message is populated with wrong content.

I use custom cell for displaying messages.Here is my code (simplified):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Im using storyboard, so I don't need if (!cell) part
    RightMessageCell *cell =  (RightMessageCell *) [self.messageTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"right_text_message"];

    [self configureCell:cell forIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [self configureCell:self.offscreenCell forIndexPath:indexPath];
     [self.offscreenCell setNeedsLayout];
     [self.offscreenCell layoutIfNeeded];

     result = [self.offscreenCell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;
}

- (void) configureCell:(RightMessageCell *) cell forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath {
    ChatMessageModel *message = [self.fetchController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]; 
    rightMessageCell.messageTextView.text = message.messageText;
}
```

And FRC methods:

```
#pragma mark - NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.messageTableView beginUpdates];
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {
    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.messageTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.messageTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self.messageTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.messageTableView endUpdates];
}
```

But I can't figure out why newly created cells comes with previous cells content and replace their own content when they are redrawn (for ex when I scroll up and down)

Comment: Is that your actual code? What is `rightMessageCell` in the `configureCell:...` method?

Comment: @MartinR it's a subclass for message cell, holding outlet for text messageTextView

Comment: I mean the `rightMessageCell` variable, not the `RightMessageCell` class. Shouldn't that be `cell.messageTextView.text = ...`?

Comment: @user2786037 I'm seeing the same thing Martin is.  You pass a cell to configure into configureCell and then ignore it by setting the message text into some other cell (rightMessageCell).  My guess is you need to use cell.messageTextView.text = ... instead of rightMessageCell...

Comment: @MartinR oh, sorry, it's a mistake in question, not in code..

Answer (score 3):

In your `UITableViewCell` subclass you need to implement this method:

```
-(void)prepareForReuse {
    [super prepareForResuse];
    [self.textLabel setText:nil];
    // reset layout
    // reset text on your labels
    // reset other properties such as images or text colour
}
```

This is called before a UITableViewCell is about to be reused, so that is your chance to reset the content/layout to default.

Another area I see that there's an issue is `cell` vs `rightMessageCell` here:

```
- (void) configureCell:(RightMessageCell *) cell forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath {
    ChatMessageModel *message = [self.fetchController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]; 
    rightMessageCell.messageTextView.text = message.messageText;
}
```

Your code shouldn't even be able to compile with the above method.

Comment: this is a good place to look when you're having issues with cell's briefly showing the wrong contents or when filling cell contents asynchronously.  In this case it's unlikely to have much effect as the issue is long-term and only resolves when the cell is refreshed.

Comment: I believe with that snippet, he would only have an empty string in his cell. The problem is that the text is not properly set after the cell is being reused.

Comment: I've already tried to do it, but I cant understand why text is not overwritten by cellForIndexPath method. Another problem is how to reset layout. Can you please go into more details why I should set text to nil, even if I set text to the same outlet in cellForIndexPath method and show how to reset layout?

Comment: You definitely don't have to set the text to nil if you're setting the text on re-use of the cell. Setting images and text to nil is always a good idea, especially if you're loading images asynchronously, then your placeholder image won't be the last displayed image.